# Add a button to classroom FABs

Tags: google-classroom

i want to add a button to the Google Classroom FAB (see picture below) if a user has signed up on my app? I have seen some apps doing that, but i am not sure where to begin with implementing it. I can't find anything about it in the docs. Thanks.

[image: Google Classroom FAB]

Comment: I think that you'll have to implement it by yourself. You should create a Floating Action Button (FAB) in your app (here is the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button) for it).

Comment: Also you can check out this following references: [Android floating action button animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46gQrf2M5pU), [Working with Android FAB (Floating Action Button) Animations](https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-floating-action-button-animations.html), and [Animating an Android Floating Action Button](https://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button/). After that add the function regarding Classroom and create an API call. Hope this helps.